# Best Practice for retrieving secrets securely

Tags: secret-sharing, secrets-management

So a company I work with currently is using a password management system that lets us retrieve the passwords for an application by providing a secure key to an API.  Currently, the key is stored in the code of the app so it is passed to the API easily.

My belief is that it is insecure and a best practice would be to use .env files (this is a Node JS app) to set environment variables for the key.  Do not let them be checked into the code repo and when the code is deployed to a K8s system, have the key for production injected as environment variables from the K8s Secrets system.  Of course, we could just inject the password as an environment variable, but the former lets us manage the passwords in the management system.

The powers that be that control our K8s systems and other operations don't like the idea.  They say that no one should be able to see the password or key anywhere.  They argue that "Google doesn't let every developer have access to production passwords.  They don't let every administrator be able to look up any key".  I don't work at Google and neither did any of them, so I can't speak to how they do it.

My belief is that you have to trust some people.  If they want to keep the production key private to only be controlled by the administrators, then I am all for it.  As long as I can get to the development and QA keys to get those passwords, all should work.

Is there some other method I am not seeing that I can get the hire ups to buy into that anyone else can propose?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying that the key is hard coded in the application code, and not some sort of configuration file.  Is this correct?

Comment: Also, may I confirm the information you are suggesting get stored in the env file?  Are you suggesting the key to the password management API get stored there, or are you suggesting that the actual passwords get stored there?

Comment: @DanLandberg I think the API communicates the secret key just like Azure Key Vault does for example.

Comment: @DanLandberg, currently keys are hard coded in the application code when we pull the secrets from an API.  My suggestion was to use Environment Variables for storing the keys.  Using a .env file for local development by developers and setting the variables when testing locally.  When deployed to a K8s cluster, having Kubernetes Secrets inject the environment variables for the password API keys and still retrieving password values from that API

Comment: how is a strategy with greater access to the secret less secure than than a hard-coded key a fewer number of devs have access to? You can easily store secrets in a library file that is git ignore'd to keep such info out of the repo.

Comment: @dandavis It's not.  That is my claim.  The company I work for wants a secure solution and agrees the current situation is not secure at all with values in source control.  The issue is they don't want devs to have access to anything, nor do they even want DevOps people to have access to keys in the Jenkins or K8s systems to build the images.  I am trying to find a recommendation I can point at to them and say "See?  You HAVE to trust somebody somewhere along the line."